# function aliases

Tags: r

In R I have two functions that pretty much do the same thing except they have a different set of default variables.

 Say I have `function1<-function(a=1,b=2,c=3){...}`what I have right now is function 2 calling function 1 except defining a different set of default variables `function2<-function(a=3,b=4,c=5){function1(a=a,b=b,c=c)}` 

obviously this is not optimal and I was wondering if there is a better way to write these two functions (maybe have a common function and make the other two aliases with different default variables?)

Comment: Why do you think this is not optimal? This seems a perfectly reasonable thing to do.

Comment: A function that simply calls another function seems redundant

Comment: I call it convenient. I think this kind of thing happens all the time in package development. I consider it one sign of thoughtful design, i.e. a master function can handle all cases.  Then the package owner creates some convenience functions for typical cases.

Answer (score 2):

You can modify default parameters by `formals<-`.

```
> f1 <- function(a = 1) a
> f2 <- f1
> formals(f2)$a <- 2
> 
> f1
function(a = 1) a
> f2
function (a = 2) 
a
> 
> f1()
[1] 1
> f2()
[1] 2
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you could just add another argument to the original function that acts as a flag to indicate which set of defaults to use:

```
function1 <- function(a=1, b=2, c=3, altDefaults = FALSE){
    if (altDefaults){
        a <- 3; b <- 4; c <- 5
    }
}
```

One could expand this I suppose to incorporate multiple sets of defaults but it might get cumbersome.

Comment: well I still want to have two functions no matter what

Comment: @Ellipsis... In that case, I think the solution you suggest in your question would be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this [wiki](https://github.com/hadley/devtools/wiki/First-class-functions) on first order functions by Hadley. One of the functions discussed is `Curry` which allows you to define variants of a function just like what you mentioned in your question.